# Bizarre behaviour of onclick method within list view

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

I'm experiencing the following extremely bizarre situation. I have a listview with a button in each item. One of the things the button does is change the color and size of the button text. When I press the button, the situation described in the picture below occurs. If I press the button in the first item, the method is executed for the first item, and for the first item which isn't visible on screen. Similarly, if I do this for the second item, the same occurs with the second item not visible on the screen. I am truly baffled by this. I tried adding an onClickListener to my adapter instead of using the method seperately, I've also tried using `b.setTextSize()` instead of looking for the button in the listview. The logging returns only the item I click on, and everything appears to be fine, but it is not.

[image]

Here is the list adapter and holder :

```html
 class ViewHolder {
        TextView leaguetxt;
        TextView datetxt;
        TextView teamstxt;
        TextView bettxt;
        TextView betid;
        TextView typetxt;
        TextView commentstxt;
        Button oddsbtn;
        LinearLayout item;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            leaguetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.leaguetxt);
            datetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.datetxt);
            teamstxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
            bettxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
            betid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gid);
            typetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.difficultytxt);
            commentstxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.commenttxt);
            oddsbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
            item = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
        }
    }
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(AllGameslistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, tomee);

        }
        public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<TipDisplayer> tomee) {
            super(AllGameslistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, tomee);
            tomee = tomee;  // declare tomee in the Adapter, don't use static

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View itemView = convertView;
            TipDisplayer currentwriter = tomee.get(position);
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
                itemView.setTag(holder);
                Log.d("SETTING","new holder");

            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
                Log.d("plzwork",ids.toString());
                if (!ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(holder.betid.getText().toString()))) {
                    //holder.oddsbtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    //holder.oddsbtn.setTextSize(18);
                    Log.d("doesn't contain", "doesn't contain");
                    Log.d("betid",holder.betid.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("bettxt", holder.bettxt.getText().toString());
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("recycling contains", "contains");
                    //holder.oddsbtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB102E"));
                    //holder.oddsbtn.setTextSize(20);
                    Log.d("betid", holder.betid.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("bettxt", holder.bettxt.getText().toString());
                }
                Log.d("Recycling","recycling");

            }
            holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
                    Button b = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
                    ListView listView = (ListView) layout.getParent();
                    final int position = listView.getPositionForView(listView);
                    String buttontext = b.getText().toString();
                    Button lastchance = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
                    TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gid);
                    String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
                    TipDisplayer currentwriter = tomee.get(position + 1);
                    Log.d("plzworkkkk", newBet.toString());
                    if (ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(betid))) {
                        ids.remove(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(betid)));
                        Log.d("plzworkkkkkkk", newBet.toString());
                        currentwriter.toggleHighlighted();
                        //checkhighlight(layout);
                        Log.d("getodds", buttontext);
                        selection = "home";

                        TextView teamss = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
                        String teams = teamss.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("teams", teams);
                        TextView bet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
                        String bettxt = bet.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("btxttext", bettxt);
                        newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, false, teams, selection, bettxt);
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                        if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            stake = 0.00;
                            newwinnings = 0.00;
                            potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");

                        } else {
                            mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                              int count, int after) {
                                }

                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                          int before, int count) {
                                    if (s.length() != 0) {
                                        stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                                    } else {
                                        stake = 0.00;
                                        newwinnings = 0.00;
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                                    }
                                }

                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                }
                            });
                            //stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
                            newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                            potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                            newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


                        }
                    } else {

                        ids.add(Integer.parseInt(betid));
                        //checkhighlight(layout);
                        currentwriter.toggleHighlighted();
                        selection = "home";
                        String getodds = lastchance.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("getoddsss", getodds);
                        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                        if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            stake = 0.00;
                            newwinnings = 0.00;
                            TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                            potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");
                        } else {
                            mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                              int count, int after) {
                                }

                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                          int before, int count) {
                                    if (s.length() != 0) {
                                        stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                                    } else {
                                        stake = 0.00;
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                                    }
                                }

                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                }
                            });
                            stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
                            TextView teamms = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
                            String teams = teamms.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("teams", teams);
                            TextView bet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
                            String bettxt = (String) bet.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("bettxt", bettxt);
                            newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, true, teams, selection, bettxt);
                            double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                            newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                            TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                            TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                            myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                            potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                            newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


                        }
                    }

                }
            });





            String leaguetext = currentwriter.getLeague();
            String datetext = currentwriter.getDatetimer();
            String teamstext = currentwriter.getTeams();
            String bettext = currentwriter.getBet();
            String typetext = currentwriter.getType();
            String idtext = currentwriter.getId();
            String commentsText = currentwriter.getComments();
            String oddstext = currentwriter.getOdds();
            holder.leaguetxt.setText(leaguetext);
            holder.datetxt.setText(datetext.substring(0,datetext.lastIndexOf(":")) + " GMT");
            holder.teamstxt.setText(teamstext);
            holder.bettxt.setText(bettext);
            holder.betid.setText(idtext);
            holder.commentstxt.setText(commentsText);
            holder.oddsbtn.setText(oddstext);
            holder.typetxt.setText(typetext);
            if (typetext.equals("Low Risk")) {
                holder.typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067103"));
            }
            else if (typetext.equals("Medium Risk")) {
                holder.typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D9D216"));
            }
            else if (typetext.equals("Longshot")) {
                holder.typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F75528"));
            }


            return itemView;


        }
    }

    private void PopulateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter(tomee);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that as soon as the first item is not visible on the screen, its layout is recycled and used for the next item which is shown in the listview, this means that if the first item is highlighted, as soon as we scroll to the first not visible item, it will also be highlighted since it using the view of the first item which is highlighted. Explained in this video at 11:45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k .

In order to solve this add the following code:

```
@Override

public int getViewTypeCount() {                 

return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `lastchance.setTag("highlighted");` to set a tag to highlighted. Add a member variable like, `private boolean highlighted` to `TipCollector`.

Then in your activity have a `onListItemClick()` that will toggle it like:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    this.toggleHighlighted();
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your TipDisplayer class:

```
public void toggleHighlighted() {  
  highlighed = !highlighted; 
}
```

Then in on your getView() method you can add something like:

```
 if (currentwriter.isHighlighed()) { 
    change color code here 
 }
```

Comment: wouldn't that mean that the list view would have to be reloaded every time a button is pressed for these changes to take affect? What I want to do is to load it once and then highlight/unhighlight when I press a button

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you would have to reload your data set in that case.   I think you should try the view holder pattern that @ClaytonOliveira recommended using.

Comment: Since I use the setTag() already to store the "highlighted/not highlighted" state, would I have to implement an invisible textview to store that info and use the setTag() for the holder?

Comment: I implemented the viewholder, its still behaving the same way tho, I posted the code above

Comment: I think the only way to make this work the way you want is to make the highlighted state be based on an object property.  Then you can set what you want highlighted in your `getView()` adapter method. You will need to call an `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` everytime you toggle the highlighted state.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for the past 3 days and it's stopping me from progressing with development, could you please make a small example or alter my code and post it as an answer so I understand what you mean exactly. I'd be extremely grateful. :)

Comment: I edited my answer above to add an example of what I was thinking

Comment: Would this allow me to have more than one event highlighted simulatenously?

Comment: so I implemented your method, and its still doing the same thing funny enough, no idea what to do anymore :/

Comment: Is your codebase public? I can could clone it on my computer and look at what the exact problem is.

Comment: It requires database connections to work, I can't really hand that out...but the thing is that the rest of the method is executed fine; aka all the calculations are proper, the only improper thing is the highlighting. I played around a bit with the handler but I still get odd behaviours. I'll update my code in the question so that you can have a look.

Comment: I commented out the highlighting as it was interfering with my further development. Pretend the comments aren't there

Answer (score 0):

A ListView typically contains more data than the number of displayed rows. If the user scrolls the list, then rows and their associated views are being scrolled out of the visible area. The Java objects which represents the rows can be reused for newly visible rows.

If Android determines that a row is not visible anymore, it allows the getView() of the adapter method to reuse the associated view via the convertView parameter.

The adapter can assign new data to the views contained in the view hierarchy of the convertView. This avoids inflating an XML file and creating new Java objects.

In case Android cannot reuse a row, the Android system passes null to the convertView parameter. Therefore the adapter implementation needs to check for this.

You can use the ViewHolder pattern to solve your problem, take a look at this link for reference and code example:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I would use it here? I read through the link but I'm still a bit confused on how it would be used in this case.